# I am living in Germany. My residence permit expires on 31st August 2021. Can I book my flight to India on 1st September 2021?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, tickets

I  am living in Germany. My residence permit expires on 31st August 2021. Can I book my flight to India on 1st September 2021? Will there be any penalty? Will, there be any penalty, or will I face any problem the next time I come

Comment: Depends on your citizenship. If you are Indian, you would be overstaying by exactly one day. They probably won't stop you leaving, but they might note it the next time you apply for a visa and they might reject your application.

Comment: I don’t think anyone can answer that question with 100% certainty. Why take the risk? Much better to leave before your residence permit expires and not have the uncertainty about how the slight overstay might be perceived hanging over all future visa applications

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you leave Germany directly, leaving 1 day after the residence permit has expired is no problem.

Should your citizenship require a visa for other Schengen Countries, the residence permit can only be used as a visa replacement while it is valid.

---

Accourding to the **Administrative regulation** (quoted below), a period of 1 month is considered to be 'without delay'.

> **Verwaltungsvorschrift: 50.2.3**
> Eine Ausreisefrist von einem Monat nach Beendigung des rechtmäßigen Aufenthalts ist im Regelfall ausreichend.
>
> > An exit period of **one month after the end of the legal stay** is usually sufficient.

**Sources**:

- [Section 50 (1) Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory - Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1042)

  - > *Such foreigners must leave the federal territory without delay or,...*
  - [Onlinekommentierung verschiedener Gesetze zum Ausländer- und Asylrecht](https://www.migrationsrecht.net/component/com_joomlaw/Itemid,232/id,286/layout,vwv/view,comment/%23)

Comment: Correct as far as it goes, but this answer does not address the OP's query about whether leaving Germany late might impact future entries or visa applications.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Since the Administrative regulation states nothing more, such an answer cannot be given. It states that when leaving within 1 month the OP obligation to leave is fulfilled within a period that is considerd sufficient. Where no charges, no crime.

Comment: If one considers the word "usually" in Section 50.2.3 to be an absolute, then yes, leaving a day late should satisfy German authorities. Whether other country authorities would know of the German rule, or construe "usually" in the same way, is unknown. While the question suggested the OP was talking about a return to Germany, they didn't say exactly that. I think a complete answer would include this issue as well.

Comment: You have both incorrectly interpreted and translated the section from the administrative regulation, which you are quoting. The section you are quoting deals with departure deadlines (not 'exit periods' as you translate the German term), which are set if a person is to be deported, but is given a chance to leave voluntarily within a granted 'grace' period. It has no relevance for this situation where a residence permit expires as scheduled.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica There was a case at **expatriates**, where charges were made because of a few days. The OP later reported that the charges were withdrawn, I believe, due to Geringfügigkeit (Insignificance). How do you expect that someone here will know what other country authorities know or not? That would be wild speculation.

Comment: I agree: we cannot know. I think, however, that the answer should contain a statement that while we don't know if leaving Germany late will affect subsequent applications or entries, that leaving late might do so. That's more useful than not mentioning the issue.. Not mentioning the issue suggests that leaving late isn't a problem, while in reality it might have significance, particularly in countries other than Germany.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Sorry, but not even an Immigration Lawyer could give a reliable answer as to how other countries would react.

Comment: I agree — I said so above: we cannot know. But the possibility of an issue, IMO, justifies a mention of that possibility.